# IBM WCM Plugin:RequestAttribute is not working, when used on published site ( only preview is working)

Tags: websphere-portal, wcm, ibm-wcm

I've made a menu component to create tabs which contains rendered results from another menu component.

The internal component is using Location/Site Areas (set by Query string) as a criteria and in the main component I use `[Plugin:RequestAttribute(...)]` to set the Site Area I want the content from in specific tab. In order to do so, I put the internal component inside `[InContext(...)][/InContext]` tags - in this case **Result design** code of the main component is:

```
title="[Property field="title"]">

[Plugin:RequestAttribute key="year" mode="set" value="[Property field='title']"]

[InContext context="autofill"]
[Component name="omantel_en/investors/financial snapshots/financial statement menu" startPage="" resultsPerPage=""]
[/InContext]
</div>
```

The header ends with `<div class="tab selected"`, while separator is set as `<div class="tab"` which in the end construct a valid HTML structure (of that I'm sure).

Tabbing is held by javascript I put in the beggining of header and works fine.

Everything works fine while using `Preview` option - content is generated properly, I can even use `Preview` on site I actually want the component to be used on and this will give me desired result.

The problem occurs when I put the main menu component tag in published Article. Then it shows only tabs, without any content from the inner component. It looks as if the `[Plugin:RequestAttribute(...)]` tag that is used as substitute for Query string stops working.

I already tried to put the main menu component tag (in the actual Article) inside `[InContext(...)][/InContext]`(with all of possible options) but it gave no good result. I'm kind of new in using IBM websphere~.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was a problem with Libraries - I simply put wanted content in single library and now it works fine.